# AJAX calls done during javascript initialization follow cache rules of browser however later on calls do not

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, cache-control

I've recently started using JQuery AJAX calls to fetch some content within a document ready function.  I am setting headers for cache control in the AJAX call that get overridden when a forced reload of the page is done (Chrome) which is exactly what I want.

Unfortunately later on calls to AJAX through user interaction after the page and content is completely materialized do not follow these cache rules.

For instance if I control-reload a page that initially accesses /dostuff/ during initialization with a cache control header set to an obscenely high max age time the browser overrides the cache control header and sets the max age to 0 which is nice.. it gives the 
user a lot of control to refresh content.

Is this proper?  Should I always expect AJAX calls that are part of initialization to override request headers the way I'm beginning to expect them to.  It seems like there is a lot of room for inconsistency.

If I call the same URL later on it does what I want and the browser automagically adds in an if-modified-since header that helps me return properly from the server.

If I call a URL that hasn't been part of the initialization however.. like /dootherstuff/ ..  It won't set the max age to 0 if the page initialized through a force reload.

I don't expect the be able to fix this problem since it appears to be working as it should be..  I would however like to know how to reliably detect if the page was force reloaded so that I can handle the cache control headers properly.

Resolving this issue using version keys on the URL that are fudged to deal with reloads, rather than actual content versions, will cause me a lot of grief and extra network traffic and processing time.